# Casting BasicDBList to Java Arraylist

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist, mongo-java-driver

I am having a difficulty. I have retrieved a BasicDBList from database but now I want to iterate over the list but I cannot do it in it's BasicDBList format. So I want to ask that how can we cast BasicDBList to ArrayList of Java. Here is what I have tried.

```
DBCursor cursor1 = coll2.find();
DBObject main1 = cursor1.next();
ArrayList<String[]> ans = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ans.add(((String[]) main1.get("Data")));
```

but I am having following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the BasicDBList to a String array, not an ArrayList.

**Replace**

`ans.add(((String[]) main1.get("Data")));`

**with**

`ans.add(((ArrayList<String>) main1.get("Data")));`

See the [Java docs](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBList.html).